# Does Bertrand's Paradox depend on the Axiom of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, paradoxes

This is the set up to Bertrand's Paradox:

> Randomly choose two points on a circle. Construct a line segment (circle chord) between them. Construct an inscribed equilateral triangle within the circle. What is the probability that the (randomly chosen) chord is *longer* than one side of the triangle?

[image]

Three equally compelling approaches to this puzzle lead two three solutions: $\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}$ (I won't describe those solutions here. Grant Sanderson does so eloquently in this [video by Numberphile](https://youtu.be/mZBwsm6B280).)

Monte Carlo simulations can be run which support each of the three solutions.

The paradox:

> How can the puzzle have three mutually exclusive correct solutions?

I am inclined to think that the question, although it appears to be well-formed, is otherwise. The culprit is here:

> Randomly choose....

The assumption is that we can choose randomly from an infinite set of points. The *Axiom of Choice* sounds like a trite assumption. Yet, we know it can lead to odd results (such as the Banach Tarski Paradox).

The question:
Am I correct in my assertion that Bertrand's Paradox relies on the Axiom of Choice? 
We assume that a choice function exists to select from an infinite set of circle chords. Furthermore, we pit three such functions against each other, and receive different results.

Comment: Bertrand's Paradox is not about choosing a chord, but about using a measure.  Different measures give different probabilities for a particular event (this should not be a surprise - they are different).  Your set up of *"Randomly choose two points on a circle"* leads to the $\frac13$ result

Comment: Assuming you mean randomly and uniformly choosing the points, there is only 1 correct answer, and it is 1/3. The axiom of choice seems irrelevant - it is possible to formulate probability theory with only countable choice, and it is even possible to make it work with no choice through some technical modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

There are three ways of calculating "probability".

1. Define a uniform distribution in the space $S^1$.
2. Define a uniform distribution on a diameter of the circle
3. Define a uniform distribution in the "interior" of the circle.

The key to the difference is the difference in defining a chord.

It is very usual for a question to have multiple plausible solutions. You probably learned that a function can only have one output for each input. But be aware that there is something called "set-valued function" in which the output is a set.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in my assertion that Bertrand's Paradox relies on the Axiom of Choice?

No, this paradox has nothing in particular to do with the axiom of choice. The fact that we use the word "choice" for both "random choice" and "the axiom of choice" is just a coincidence of language.

The "choice" in the name of the axiom of choice refers to it being possible to "make infinitely many choices" simultaneously. The typical example is: the axiom of choice is required to pick a single sock from each of infinitely many pairs of socks. It does not refer to *random choice*: even if you can pick an element from each of those pairs of socks, this says nothing about being able to make *random choices*, e.g. so that every sock is picked with probability 1/2.

In particular making finitely many choices does not require the axiom of choice.